# Is drift rate the same as interest rate in risk-neutral random walk when using Monte Carlo for option pricing?

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, risk-neutral-measure

When using following risk-neutral random walk

$$\delta S = rS \delta t + \sigma S \sqrt{\delta t} \phi$$

where $\phi \sim N(0,1)$.

Now when a text mentions drift = 5% does that mean that interest rate (r) is 5%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The risk neutral and the real path share the same volatility, so the difference is in the drift rate, where the risk-neutral path drifts with the risk-free rate r.

You may want to check out Paul Willmots [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470319585), esp. ch. 26, for applications.

Answer (score 3):

When using Monte Carlo for option pricing you numerically approximate expectation under a risk-neutral probability measure $Q$. Your undiscounted stock price process in GBM framework has as a drift equal to risk free rate under $Q$. So the answer to your question is affirmative.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. May be a basic question, what does GBM stand for?

Comment: @bytefire Geometric Brownian motion